# How to start page at center of center or at specific height after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, onload

I want to start page at the center horizontally and vertically when it had loaded (not at top), anyone any suggestions? Or at a specific height if that is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to look at the center of page content when it overflows the viewport (it has scrollbars), or to center a container object in the middle of the viewport when the container object is smaller than the viewport?

Comment: I mean when you are finished loading the page it is at the center of the window (or scroll) and not at the top, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).height()/2);
    $(window).scrollLeft($(window).width()/2);
});
```

You can change the position to what suit your needs.

Also you can use `$(window).scrollTo($(window).width()/2, $(window).height()/2);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to add the script tho with no luck, it didn't have any effect. Got any other suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer, please test it again. By mistake I put 50% instead of an integer value. I will create a simple example on jsfiddle now.

Comment: Here is another example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_scrollto

Comment: Thanks again but still no effect. I found one code that worked which is as simple as <body onLoad="window.scroll(0, 1500)"> but my <body> tag already has an onLoad <body  onload=" (function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).scroll(function() {
           if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
               $(window).scrollTop(1);
           }
           else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
               $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
           }    
       });
   }); 
 })( jQuery );">

Comment: Do you think in any way they can work together? See here if that helps http://mondieu-bureau.nu/bureau/ (where im working). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking but have you tried relative coordinates ?

like >>

```css
/*i put this all css selector for canceling all margins, paddings so i can remove default browser prefereces for the same*/
/*border box is just that any size od div is not changed after addinational padding*/
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
  body{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;height:100%;
   background-color:red;
   padding-top:10%;
   padding-left:10%;
   padding-right:10%;
   padding-bottom:10%;
  }
  centerd{
            /*relative dimensions wont work if not display:block;*/
   display:block;
   width:100%;height:100%;
   background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<title>Center Content</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<body>
 
 <centerd>
        <!--html5 element, you can create your own -->
 </centerd>
 
</body>
</html>
```

for more information visit : [it is cool way to know enough about html, css, javascript etc.](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: Thank you! But I thought more of when the page is done loading you are located at the center horizontally and vertically, or at a specific height. Not on the top of the page.

Comment: how about autofocus on the part of the page you want to display ? the theory is that what is in focus should be visible on page. I've tried modifying the tryit code on w3schools and it worked... somewhat. It automatically scrolled down to the autofocus part, but it was at the bottom.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autofocus

try adding to autofocus input id of focus. 
<style>
#focus{
margin-top:800px;
}
</style>

maybe you can put autofocus on desired part of the page and css the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Although not sure if this is what you are looking for:

To center a container (a DIV element say) horizontally, give it a fixed width and auto left and right margins in CSS:

```
div#container
{   width: 1024px; /* a fixed width container */
    border: thin solid green; /* debug, to see */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

then an anonymous JavaScript function to center a container vertically after load using its margin-top property:

```
function ()
{  var e = document.getElementById("container");
   var eHeight = e.offsetHeight;
   var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   var marginTop = 0;

   if(clientHeight > eHeight)
   {   marginTop = (clientHeight - eHeight) >> 1; // integer divide by 2
   }
   e.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
```

}

added to the page using jQuery's ready() function for the window, and HTML

```
<div id="container">
    hello this is page content
</div>
```

centers a container element in the viewport where possible

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I just use:

```
function Scrolldown() {
    window.scroll(250, 400);
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
```